# Matrix, how to solve?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

Given the matrix M x N. How to print the number of the line containing the maximum number of identical elements?

```
import random
n = int(input('Введите кол-во столбцов матрицы: '))
m = int(input('Введите кол-во строк матрицы: '))
matrix = [[random.randrange(0, 10) for y in range(n)] for x in range(m)]
print(matrix)
max_x = 0
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(m):
        if max_x < matrix[i].count(matrix[i][j]):
            print(matrix.index(matrix[i]))
            max_x = matrix[i].count(matrix[i][j])
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import random

n = int(input('Введите кол-во столбцов матрицы: ')) #columns
m = int(input('Введите кол-во строк матрицы: '))    #rows
matrix = [[random.randrange(0, 10) for y in range(n)] for x in range(m)]

for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        print(matrix[i][j], end = " ")
    print()

max_x = 0
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(n):
        if max_x < matrix[i].count(matrix[i][j]):
            max_x = i

print(max_x)
```

If M are number of rows than your first for i in range needs to be m value.
I'm assuming that variable max_x is searched line and by line you mean row. If that's the case than in max_x save the line with the maximum number of identical. Check if `max_x < matrix[i].count(matrix[i][j])` and then save index of that row `max_x = matrix.index(matrix[i])`.
NOTE: In this case it saves the index of the first row that has the most identical numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro! I`m a beginner and its my first time here. I cant even rightly write question)). Cause my ENG is so so. But thanks a lot. I hope you`ll help me in future again if some problems ))

Comment: Once again bro. How can i show that if i have not a repeating element with adding else statement?

Comment: No problem. We were all once beginners. Just next time explain the problem as best you can for the people who don't have much time on their hand so they can read through the code easier.

Comment: Use if matrix[i].count(matrix[i][j]) == 1 statement. That shows that the element doesn't repeat in that row (means it has 1 element of that value). You don't need the else statement for that.

Comment: Thanks. I got it i`ll try:)